# Pointer to a pointer function ---> how to return a pointer

Tags: c

I have this pointer to pointer function that takes two arguments and it is suppose to return pointer to the array. But what is the proper way to return pointer to the array in this case? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **multiTable (unsigned int xs, unsigned int ys)
{
    unsigned int i, j;

    int **table = malloc( ys * sizeof(*table)); 
          // should I put malloc(ys * xs * sizeof(*table))?

    for(i = 0; i < ys; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < xs; j++)
        {
           table[i][j] = (j+1) * (i+1);
        }

    }

    return table;  //what would be the proper way to return table? Is this ok?

    free(**table); //by the way, do I need this? 
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum = multiTable2(3,2);

    return 0;
}
```

what would be the proper way to return table? Is what I written the return table; ok or should it be like return *table or even return **table? And also, do I need to free the table?

Comment: You allocate `table`, but you don't allocate `table[x]`, leading to [*undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which you also have in that `free` call.

Comment: Then your assignment in the `main` function is wrong as well. All in all, your compiler should be screaming at you!

Comment: And your free call is really wrong, very much. Does this code compile?

Comment: Besides you try to `free` after return.

Comment: Yes, it does compline. So should I change the malloc to int (*table)[xs] = malloc(ys * sizeof(*table));

Comment: Mostly my question is, is the return table correct? And is it necessary to free the table in this case?

Comment: Or would the malloc be right, if I would right it: int **table = malloc(ys * xs * sizeof(*table))?

Comment: oops, misclick upvote. You can't use that malloc form if you are returning `int **`.  Because `int **` means pointer to a pointer, so you have to have some pointers . You'd need to change the function to also return `int (*)[xs]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **multiTable(unsigned int xs, unsigned int ys)
{

    unsigned int i, j;
    int **table;

    table = malloc(ys * sizeof(int *)); /* you need space for ys integer arrays */
    if (table == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0 ; i < ys ; i++)
    {
        table[i] = malloc(xs * sizeof(int)); /* you need space for xs integers */
        if (table[i] != NULL) /* did malloc succeed? */
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < xs ; j++)
                table[i][j] = (j + 1) * (i + 1);
        }
    }
    return table;
}

int main()
{
    int **sum;

    sum = multiTable(3, 2);
    /* do somenthing with sum here */
    if (sum != NULL)
    {
        /* now you must use free, like this */
        unsigned int i;
        for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
        {
            if (sum[i] != NULL)
                free(sum[i]);
        }
        free(sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this could be done, but you need to read more to understand the basics.

Your problem is not

> how to return a pointer

but instead how to use `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: If I would like to use only one malloc, would this work: int (*table)[xs] = malloc(ys * sizeof(*table))

Comment: Or int **table = malloc(ys * xs * sizeof(*table))?

Comment: no, it would be something like `int *table = malloc(xs * ys * sizeof(int))` but then you would need to compute the index your self.

Comment: I mean to get the `i,j` element you do it this way `table[i * columnCount + j]`.

Answer (score 0):

> If I would like to use only one malloc, would this work: int
>   (*table)[xs] = malloc(ys * sizeof(*table))

Yes, it would, if you adjust the function according to Matt McNabb's comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*multiTable(unsigned int xs, unsigned int ys))[]
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    int (*table)[xs] = malloc(ys * sizeof *table);
    for (i = 0; i < ys; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < xs; j++)
       table[i][j] = (j+1) * (i+1);
    return table;
}

int main()
{
    const int xs = 3, ys = 2;
    int (*sum)[xs];
    sum = multiTable(xs, ys);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ys; i++, puts(""))
    for (j = 0; j < xs; j++)
       printf("%d", sum[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```